Line drawn with easeljs - edges are not crisp
The edges are not sharp when drawing with easeljs. For straight line its okay, but the issue is for line with slope.
Sample image of line


var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);


function drawLine() {
  var line = new createjs.Shape();
  line.graphics.moveTo(100, 50).setStrokeStyle(1).beginStroke("#F2CC0C").lineTo(500, 80);
  stage.addChild(line);

}

function drawShapes() {
  drawLine();
  stage.update();
}

drawShapes();
#testCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #000;
}
<script src="//code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.09.25.combined.js"></script>
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="600" height="150"></canvas>




Make the line thicker.
